# ROS Install on Pandaboard trouble linking ASSIMP 3 collada_urdf

Tags: build, collada-urdf, pandaboard, rosinstall, linking

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have followed this guide to install ROS on my Pandaboard: `ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/PandaBoard/Source`

I have gotten to package 100/103 in the build (collada_urdf) and it fails to build giving me this error:

`/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/collada_urdf/lib/libcollada_urdf.so: undefined reference to` ``aiScene::aiScene()'`

I added `set(IS_ASSIMP3 1)` and
`add_definitions(-DIS_ASSIMP3)` to the CMakeLists.txt for collada_urdf but with no luck.

Also, I followed the build instructions to build Assimp 3.

If anyone can provide any suggestions I would really appreciate it.

Full out put of sudo ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --pkg collada_urdf:

pastebin.com/3zLmKYJZ

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61239/ros-install-on-pandaboard-trouble-linking-assimp-3-collada_urdf/) by [swillis11](https://answers.ros.org/users/4721/swillis11/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-04-21

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2013-04-22**:
If you don't need collada_urdf, you can try removing it from your src folder and rebuilding.

I've been using the Ubuntu ARM debs with good success: http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/UbuntuARM . No collada_urdf build there either, but I haven't needed it yet.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-04-22**:
I think this is related to: https://github.com/ros/robot_model/pull/15#issuecomment-16760508

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the problem is that you have Assimp 2.0 also on the system.  collada_urdf then gets confused because it finds Assimp 2.0 and does not bother to check for Assimp 3.0 which is needed by collada_urdf.

You must remove Assimp 2.0:
sudo apt-get remove libassimp2 libassimp-dev

Make sure Assimp 3.0 is installed and the path to the assimp.pc file is listed in your PKG_CONFIG_PATH.

Recompile everything and it should work.

---

Originally posted by [Raptor](https://answers.ros.org/users/3237/raptor/) with karma: 377 on 2013-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1